# Увеличить длину массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Необходимо увеличить длину массива, дублируя элементы, до тех пор, пока его длина не станет требуемой.

Например, от 4 до 10 элементов:

[`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`] => [`a, a, a`, `b, b, b`, `c, c`, `d, d`]

Или такой пример: от 2 до 8 элементов:

[`a`, `b`] => [`a, a, a, a`, `b, b, b, b`]

---

Моя попытка - от 4 до 8:

```js
a = [2, 3, 1, 4];
b = [];

for(var i = 0; i< a.length;++i){
  b.push(a[i]);
  b.push(a[i]);
}

a = b;

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Может быть опишите точнее что надо сделать, а также покажите, что пытались сделать и что не получилось.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Дублировать элементы до тех пор пока есть место в массиве

Comment: Все равно не понятно. Какие элементы дублировать? Сколько раз каждый элемент дублировать? Желательно все пояснения отражать в вопросе, а не в комментариях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Длину нового массива делим на длину исходного. Округляем в меньшую сторону - это будет количество повторений элемента в новом массиве. Если после деления есть остаток, то по единичке повторений разбрасываем на каждый элемент, пока остаток не иссякнет.

Пример реализации, в котором комментариев и "украшательств" больше, чем кода по вопросу:

```js
// Растянуть массив.
function stretchArray(arr, limit) {
  if (!arr.length || limit < arr.length) {
    throw new Error('Не удалось растянуть массив.');
  }

  // Целое число, на которое будет размножен каждый элемент.
  const integer = Math.floor(limit / arr.length);

  // a % b - остаток от деления.
  // По единичке будем накидывать на каждый элемент.
  // Кому досталось, тому досталось, как `крошки` со стола.
  let crumbs = limit % arr.length;

  const newArr = Array.from(arr, function(item, index) {
    // Сколько раз нужно размножить элемент массива.
    const repeater = integer + (crumbs > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    // Уменьшаем количество `крошек`.
    crumbs--;

    // Размножаем элемент массива и возвращаем.
    return Array(repeater).fill(item);
  });
  
  // [[1, 1], [2, 2]] => [1, 1, 2, 2]
  return [].concat(...newArr);

  // Можно с помощью `flat`:
  // return newArr.flat();
}

// Исходные данные для примера.
const first = ['a', 'b'];
const second = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const third = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const fourth = [2, 3, 1, 4];

// Распечатаем результаты.
const print = (data) => JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

pre_first.textContent = print(stretchArray(first, 6));
pre_second.textContent = print(stretchArray(second, 8));
pre_third.textContent = print(stretchArray(third, 10));
pre_fourth.textContent = print(stretchArray(fourth, 23));
```

```css
pre {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #6610f2;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<h4>6: ['a', 'b']</h4>
<pre id="pre_first"></pre>

<h4>8: ['a', 'b', 'c']</h4>
<pre id="pre_second"></pre>

<h4>10: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']</h4>
<pre id="pre_third"></pre>

<h4>23: [2, 3, 1, 4]</h4>
<pre id="pre_fourth"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Могу накидать решение на Java) Интерпретируйте в JS. Я думаю суть будет понятна Вам.

```
public class DynaArray {
    private int[] array;
    private int size;

    public DynaArray() {
        array = new int[10];
    }

    public void add(int element) {
        if (size == array.length) {
            int[] temp = array;
            array = new int[temp.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                array[i] = temp[i];
            }
        }
        array[size++] = element;
    }
```

В строке `array = new int[temp.length * 2];` можно указать, на сколько увеличить массив при переполнении.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ["a", "b"];

const increase = (arr, length) => {
  let count = 0;
  let obj = {};

  const func = (arr, obj, length) => {
    arr.forEach(i => {
      arr.forEach(j => {
  
        if (i == j) {
          count++;
        }
  
      });
  
      obj[i] = count;
      count = 0;
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let min = Math.min(...Object.values(obj));

      for (let value in obj) {
        if (arr.length != length) {
          if (obj[value] == min) {
            arr.push(value)
            obj[value] = min + 1;
            i = 0;
          }
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    arr.sort();

    return arr;
  }

  return func(arr, obj, length)
}

console.log(increase(arr, 5));
```

Как-то так